# 2D cyclic background in spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a ball popping game that I've been working for a while now. I have multiple levels. In many levels, there's a bounding box by the width and the height of the screen as in:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

However I want a level where there's no bounding box, but when a ball goes to offscreen from the right, I want it to spawn back from the left. Below is a graphic illustration of what I'm talking about

[image: Screenshot from the game]
The pink ball to the right is going in the black arrow direction with an applied force of F. I want the pink ball to respawn from the bottom corner where I horribly scribed with reddish color and go the red pointed direction unless there's a collision with the other balls. The problem is the ball should not just disappear and respawn, but it should be a seamless transition.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */



for (SKNode *node in self.children) {

    CGPoint position = node.position;
    if (position.x > self.scene.size.width + node.frame.size.width/2 || position.y > self.scene.size.height + node.frame.size.height/2) {

        position.x = remainder(position.x, self.scene.size.width) - node.frame.size.width/2;
        position.y = remainder(position.y, self.scene.size.height) - node.frame.size.height/2;

    }

    node.position = position;
}


}
```

This is what I've tried in the update method but I can't get it seamless enough. Here to make it more seamless the ball comes from the other side when it completely disappears from one side. That's not what I want. If x% of the ball is out of bounds, I want to see that x% in the otherside simultaneously. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111042/how-to-make-skspritenode-reappear-on-the-opposite-side-of-its-skscene

Comment: Although I searched for an hour before opening up this question, thanks for the warning. However that solution does not work.

Comment: can you be more specific? What about that solution doesn't work?

Comment: I created another sprite that comes from the opposite side but when it's touched app crashes for some other reason.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the details on how you tried to implement that and where it crashed?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's not an exact duplicate and is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want part of the ball to be visible on each side of the screen, you are going to need to have a second sprite for the ball while it is "crossing". To allow crossing for every possible direction, you would need four sprites in total (notably when the ball is going into a corner).

If you don't need this behavior (i.e. the balls appear once they have completely disappeared), you can implement this really easily using the modulus operator. You could roughly have `ball.x %= screenWidth` and `ball.y %= screenHeight` after your position calculations.